# Message send, receiver not getting the message. Socket programing

Tags: c, sockets

I'm receiving a message from the client, comparing it and sending a message according to the result in the comparison. The server sends the message (apparently), but the client stays in the reading processes.

Server:

> Waiting for incoming connections...Press Ctrl+C to end server
>
> Connection from 127.0.0.1, port 54918 Message Recieved:c Random es 5
>   Into IFs 1er IF

```
void
result(int sockfd)
{
    ssize_t     n;
    char        buf[MAXLINE];
    int         temp;
    time_t      ticks;
    int         i;
again:
    while ((n =read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)> 0))
    {
     buf[n] = '\0';
     printf("Message Recieved:%s\n",buf);
     srand (time(NULL));
     temp = rand() % 15+1;
     printf("Ramdom es %i\n",temp);
     printf("Into IF\n");    
     if ((strncmp (buf,"A",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf,"a",1) == 0))
     {
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Option A chosen times %i on on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
      Writen(sockfd, buf, n);
      printf("1st IF\n");
     }
     else if ((strncmp (buf,"B",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf,"b",1) == 0))
     {
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Option B chosen times %i on on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
      Writen(sockfd, buf, n);
      printf("2nd IF\n");
     }
     else
     {
       printf("Incorrect Input");
       Close(sockfd);
       break;
     }  
    }
    if (n < 0 && errno == EINTR)
    goto again;
    else if (n < 0)
        err_sys("read error");
    printf("salio de funcion result\n");    
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 listenfd, connfd;
    socklen_t           len;
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr, cliaddr;
    char                buff[MAXLINE];
    /*char                message[MAXLINE];*/
    char                recvline[MAXLINE + 1];

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);/*----------------------------------------------------*/
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(5678); 

    Bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
    printf("Server is running on 127.0.0.1, listening on port 5678\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections...Press Ctrl+C to end server\n");

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &len);

        /*Client connects to server*/
        printf("\n");
        printf("Connection from %s, port %d\n",
               Inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, buff, sizeof(buff)),
               ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));


            result(connfd);
                Close(connfd);

    }
}
```

Client:

> Connect... Local Address is: 127.0.0.1:54918 
>   Starting read... 
>   Enter Option A or B: b

```
void
get_temp(FILE *fp, int sock)
{
    char    sendline[MAXLINE], recvline[MAXLINE];

    while (Fgets(sendline, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL) {

        Writen(sock, sendline, strlen(sendline));

        if (Readline(sock, recvline, MAXLINE) == 0)
            err_quit("Server Terminated Prematurely");

        Fputs(recvline, stdout);
    }
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 sockfd, n;
    socklen_t           len;
    char                recvline[MAXLINE + 1];
    struct sockaddr_in          servaddr, cliaddr;
    char  scale[2];

    if (argc != 3)
        err_quit("usage: a.out <IPaddress>");

    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        err_sys("socket error");

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port   = htons(atoi(argv[2])); 
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0) 
        err_quit("inet_pton error for %s", argv[1]);

        printf("Connect...\n");
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
        err_sys("connect error");

    len = sizeof(cliaddr);
    Getsockname(sockfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &len);
    printf("Local Address is: %s\n",
           Sock_ntop((SA *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr))); 
        printf("Starting read...\n");
    printf("Enter option A or B:  ");
        get_temp(stdin, sockfd);
    exit(0);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does `Writen` do? What is its last parameter? If that's the number of bytes to send, then that's your problem -- your sender isn't sending full lines but that's what your receiver is waiting for.

Comment: `ssize_t`      
   ` writen(int fd, const void *vptr, size_t no)`
    {
     size_t  nleft;
     ssize_t  nwritten;
     const char *ptr;

     ptr = vptr;
     nleft = no;
     while (nleft > 0) {
  if ( (nwritten = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) <= 0) {
   if (nwritten < 0 && errno == EINTR)
    nwritten = 0;  
   else
    return(-1);               }

  nleft -= nwritten;
  ptr   += nwritten;
 }
 return(no);
    }
     /* end writen */

    void
    Writen(int fd, void *ptr, size_t nbytes)
    {
 if (writen(fd, ptr, nbytes) != nbytes)
  err_sys("writen error");
    }

Comment: This is the code for writen. I dont know how to put it as a code in comments. IF someone can tell me it will be great!

Comment: @David...Thank David I changed the amount of data received in the client and it receives the data, but after that both again stuck. The server does not close the connection, nor the client exits the program...I put some printf after calling the functions get_temp and result to see if they get out of the functions, but they don't. Do you know why?

Comment: Waiting for incoming connections...Press Ctrl+C to end server

Connection from 127.0.0.1, port 34627
Message Recieved:c
Random es 11

Comment: I receive the message in the client, but my Fgets in the client is looping, it expects more input, but it should end getting input after I hit enter. The user could type a letter or multiple letters, so I don't know how big will be the input, I cannot put a fix number for Fgets. Does anyone know what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Stop coding and write a protocol specification. The specification should specify, at the byte level, what information is exchanged and how. The way you're doing it now, it's impossible for you code to be "right" or "wrong" because there is no specification for it to comply with or not comply with.

The most important thing to cover in the protocol specification is whether you have a "message" and if so, how each side finds the beginning and end of them. You can use closing the connection as a message boundary. You can use a delimiter (such as a zero byte or a newline) as a message boundary. You can prefix each message with its length.

But without a specification, your server and client will only agree on who does what, when, and how by luck.